# Is there a way to get an e-mail when a new question is asked in a favorite tag?

Tags: support, email, subscription

Is there a way to subscribe to new questions of a favorite tag?

I wish to contribute as much/fast as possible (in my area of expertise) and e-mail is the best way for that.

Comment: quick short comment, will expand later  - make use of [tag filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/new)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [tag filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) to designate your favourite tags and then have it scheduled to send emails about new questions posted to your desired email address.

[image]